# Minimum number of columns required to have a boolean value 1 in each row

Tags: c++, matrix, boolean

Give N=no. of players

K=No. of fans

likeMatrix=It is a sting array of size K where each element of array have size N.

(contains 0 and 1 only) where if a[i][j] ==1 represents fan(i) likes player(j)

Ex. N=5

K=3

like={ "10101","00001","01011","...","...." } 
Count min. no. of players required to put in team such that each fan likes atleast one player.
Here answer is 1.

One solution is to find the column each time with max number of 1's. Then remove that column and all the corresponding rows of the fans which have 1 in this paricular column. Then search again the matrix till all rows are over. Is there anything more efficient.

Comment: This algorithm of course won't work. Take a matrix ((1000)(1001)(0100)(0101)(0010)(0011)). Your solution will include all four columns, but the last one is not needed, despite having most 1s.

Comment: what you probably want to do is to solve the system of linear equations represented by `likeMatrix = [1]` where `[1]` is the column vector where each element is `1`.